# What is this file MIMEType

Tags: mime-types

I'm trying to determine the MIMEType, extension and software to use for reading a file.

It seems to me that it's a Microsoft Synchronization file, but I can't figure out exactly.

The file contains binary data with a .txt extension. What is remarkable about it are the following plain text elements at the begining of the file :

```
SDataSetSurrogate, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4fbddf16e3a769ae
...
QSystem.Data, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
....
Nmscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Is it enough to identify it ?

Answer (score 0):

Each line looks like CLI name library/resource for CLI assemblies:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_(CLI)#Satellite_assemblies

But I cannot figure out a direct MIME-Type (per line).